# Error during template rendering (invalid block tag 'nospaceless')

Tags: django, django-templates

Currently deploying Dionaea Honeypot and DionaeFR, a web based analysis which I got from github. All is well but I cant seem to access the Connection Table from the website.

I have limited knowledge in Python and Django, as well as programming in general. Below is the screenshot of the error. I tried googling

```
{% nospaceless %}
```

for both Django and Python but to no avail.

Below is the error I get in my browser:

```
Invalid block tag on line 6: 'nospaceless', expected 'endblock'. Did
you forget to register or load this tag?

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.0.2:8000/connections/
Django Version: 1.9.7
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value: Invalid block tag on line 6: 'nospaceless', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Exception Location: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py in parse, line 516
Python Executable: /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.11
```

And here is the template extract:

```
{% spaceless %}
    {% load django_tables2 %}
    {% load i18n %}
    {% block table %}
        <table {% if table.attrs %} {{ table.attrs.as_html }}{% endif %}>
            {% nospaceless %}               ← [error here]
                {% block table.thead %}
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
```

([Screenshot of error in browser here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqMOU.png))

I would be glad if someone could point me to the right direction in solving this problem.

Comment: You don't have to rush it, in case you want to see if better answers come up, but it is a good practice to show an answer was useful by either approving it or upvoting it (you'll need 15 reputation for that, you should be there soon). Welcome on SO anyway.

Answer (score 2):

No `{% nospaceless %} {% endnospaceless %}`.

Is `{% spaceless %} {% endspaceless %}`.

I only found spaceless, it works for me.

> Use the **spaceless** tag to remove whitespace between HTML tags, not whitespace within HTML tags or whitespace in plain text
>
> This tag is not meant to "optimize" the size of the generated HTML content but merely to avoid extra whitespace between HTML tags to avoid browser rendering quirks under some circumstances.

Reference href: [spaceless](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/spaceless.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just to have it documented:

The template tag "nospaceless" came from django-tables2 they removed it in  [version 1.1.0](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/e47d20aa64f0618a0f2b9e0122c986c88e4f61d8/CHANGELOG.md#v110-2016-01-19)

Comment: Make it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

There is no template tag called `nospaceless` in django. may be you wanted [`endspaceless`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#spaceless) ? however, the usage does not seem to be correct

Comment: I figured as much. Just needed confirmation. Thank you. It's not my code, it's from someone else. What about Python though?

Comment: @HarizAli what do you mean with python? Python itself doesnot have any template tags since it is not a webframework

Comment: if I delete the "nospaceless" line, will it effect the overall functionality of the code/program? Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: @HarizAli there is no dumb question! ;). I think it comes from some custom template tag, but try it :)

Comment: I delete all [nospaceless] and [endnospaceless]. And it's working without a problem now. Thank you very much. You just made my day.